# How to get user's own videos list after I passed the access token of youtube with OAuth2

Tags: oauth, youtube

How to get user's own videos list after I passed the access token of youtube with AOuth2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too general. Did you read the oauth2 guide of google?

http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html

You must get the access token and then make the request to the youtube's feed of videos passing the token by GET. Something like:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads?oauth_token=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp6

PS: There is usefull playground of Oauth1 where you can make several tests:

http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/